# Matching In Depth in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

After quite a bit of mucking around with formulas in Excel, I decided to simply ask the question.  I have a rather specific situation, that I'm frankly unsure if Excel is actually capable of handling.

I have two seperate sheets in the same workbook.

Sheet one looks something like this:

```
| id | Description |
|----|-------------|
| 1  | Apple       | 
| 2  | Apple       | 
| 3  | Banana      | 
| 3  | Grapes      |
| 4  | Apple       |
| 4  | Grapes      | 
| 4  | Banana      | 
| 4  | Lemons      |
```

And the second something like this.  Note, the second sheet has only one entry for each ID:

```
| id | Name        |
|----|-------------|
| 1  | John        | 
| 2  | Fred        | 
| 3  | Barney      | 
| 4  | Sarah       |
| 5  | Jane        |
| 6  | Rachel      | 
| 7  | Carson      | 
| 8  | Richard     |
```

What I've been trying to cobble together is an excel formula to test the descriptions only for matching ID numbers.  For example I'd like to have a column on the second sheet where it would Print Yes for any ID that had the description Banana in it.  In this case, both Barney and Sarah would have Yes in their rows, but not in the others.  I've tried both Vlookup and random If nesting, but neither seems to especially like that sheet 1 can have multiple rows with the same ID number.

Is this type of formula even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS() to return a count of where both criteria(ID,Description) are met.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!B:B,"Banana"),"Yes","no")
```

If both are met a positive number will be returned and the IF will see that as true.  If only one or none of the criteria is met then it will return `0` and the IF will see that as FALSE.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way (before `COUNTIFS()` was invented) would be an array formula which does the job as well.

```
=SUM(($A$2:$A$9=$D2)*($B$2:$B$9=F$1))
```

Explanation: Although e.g. `A2=D2` renders `TRUE` or `FALSE`, these are transformed into `1` and `0` when put within a calculation which is extremely useful when multiplying two or more conditional expressions.

[image: Screenshot]

In case you want a "yes" or "no" you may put it like this:

```
=IF(SUM(($A$2:$A$9=$D2)*($B$2:$B$9=F$1)),"yes","no")
```